# What is the difference in these 2 underlying calls to create an instance?

Tags: c#, .net

```
               Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
               assembly.CreateInstance("MyType");
```

and

```
               Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyType));
```

Ok, the Activator.CreateInstance can be generic which eliminates the need to cast your created instance, but when would you use one against the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Assembly.CreateInstance and Activator.CreateInstance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833615/difference-between-assembly-createinstance-and-activator-createinstance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string-based version looks only in the root namespace (since no namespace is included) of the **current** assembly (since no assembly name is included), plus a few system assemblies. The Type-based version already knows the type to use, so no search is necessary. It could be in any namespace or assembly,  but the implication of typeof is that you could also have used "new".

The Type approach makes more sense when you will have a Type supplied at runtime, but not usually **that** close to the object creation.

Comment: Great comment, we should marry our two comments and have little comment kids. We could name them Billy and Edwina. I know horrible name but my Grandfather's name was Billy so...

Comment: does System in this case constitute the root: System System.Text?

Comment: @Max - yes; it would need to be the full namespace, for example System.Text.Regex ( although that lacks an empty ctor so would fail for unrelated reasons)

Answer (score 2):

In the first instance you could use that methodology to create an instance dynamically without knowing the type at run time. Where as the second one you need to know the type when you're writing the code.

Comment: You could also use `Type.GetType(string typeName)` with Activator.

Comment: Excellent point. Then you wouldn't be limited to the types in the existing assembly.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious "problem" is that the former is *stringly typed* which is rarely a good thing, but it has the situational advantage of being runtime type checked so you have a level of dynamism. Personally, the refactor-factor outweighs dynamic design concerns mostly.