# What are the difference between Activator.CreateInstance() and Assembly.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Assembly.CreateInstance and Activator.CreateInstance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833615/difference-between-assembly-createinstance-and-activator-createinstance)

I am a bit confused when should I use which one. For me I think they are doing the same job. Am I right? Or are there difference.