# Dynamic object instantiation for plugin system in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, .net-4.5

I'm developing a system which needs to support customization via a plugins module. I'm coding against interfaces so that plugin code only needs to implement these interfaces in order to be able to plug into the system.

```
// for illustration purposes; not actual code
public interface IPluggable
{
    void Setup(PluginConfig c);
    bool Process(IProcessable p);
}
```

I read from configuration which plugins need to be loaded, where the assembly name and fully-qualified type name are specified.

```
<plugin assembly="Foo.Bar.PluginAssembly" type="Foo.Bar.Plugins.AwesomePlugin" />
```

Where the type `Foo.Bar.Plugins.AwesomePlugin` implements `IPluggable` and is contained in the assembly `Foo.Bar.PluginAssembly.dll`. With this information I proceed to create instances of the required plugins.

```
IPluggable plugin = (IPluggable)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName).Unwrap();
```

So my question is threefold:

1. What would be a recommended pattern for a plugin system? Does the approach I'm taking make sense or are there any obvious flaws/caveats I'm missing?
2. Is `Activator.CreateInstance()` a good choice for dynamically instantiating the plugin objects?
3. How can I be more specific about the assembly to load and its location? Say, if I want to load plugins only from assemblies located in a `.\plugins` subfolder.

Comment: One recommended pattern for a plugin system would be to use MEF : http://mef.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JamesGaunt +1. MEF is the way to go

Comment: I've been looking into MEF and I think I'll be going that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers to your questions, in order:

1. I like this and I use patterns like this when I need to write plug in components. Other people recommend using various frameworks - I know that [MEF](http://www.softwarerockstar.com/2012/04/mef-easily-creating-plugin-apps/) is very popular. But I find that using the .NET framework is easy enough for me, and learning the MEF framework is just another thing I need to learn and remember. It's probably worth a try but up to you.
2. I've always used `Assembly.CreateInstance`, but the difference is probably not going affect you ([Difference between Assembly.CreateInstance and Activator.CreateInstance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833615/difference-between-assembly-createinstance-and-activator-createinstance))
3. You simply use the `System.IO` namespace. The `DirectoryInfo` class has a method that enumerates all the files matching a given pattern (presumably `*.dll`). For each match I'd use `System.Reflection` namespace to interrogate and find any types that implement your interface, and then `CreateInstance`.

Just on MEF, my opinion is this: if I were going to be using a large, manageable and flexible plug-in system on a number of systems or projects then I'd be very interested in it, leveraging the work that other people have done to save time and avoid common pitfalls.

If I were writing a very simple, one-off plug-in system and I know the basics of how to do so using the .NET framework, I'd skip the overhead of learning MEF and write the code. I could write a reasonable plug-in process in far less than an hour, but after downloading, referencing, attempting to configure MEF - I doubt I'd have anything to show for it.

Comment: I only read the answer, but this sounds like something I did on a project a few years ago. +1